# Add content to every cell (not a event) using view resourceTimeGridWeek

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have the view resourceTimeGridWeek. I set `datesAboveResources: true`. I have about 10 ressources. So if a scroll to the right side, I have NO time info on screen (time info only at the left side before first ressource)

I want to put time information to every cell like navLinks for dayGridView.

Is there a solution? Or maybe show timeline after each day?

Comment: There's no way to do that. But you wouldn't want to, it would cause a lot of clutter on your calendar and make it ugly.

Comment: @ADyson I updated the question. I have NO time info on screen scrolling to the right. So if the user want to add a event, he doesn't know exactly what time to put the event...

Comment: can you post a screenshot and some code or something? as far as I've seen when you have a resourceTimeGrid view, it will try to compress it into the width of the calendar rather than introducing horizontal scrolling.